# Scrapy Splash is always returning the same page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

For each of several Disqus users, whose profile urls are known in advance, I want to scrape their names and usernames of their followers. I'm using `scrapy` and `splash` do to so. However, when I'm parsing the responses, it seems that it is always scraping the page of the first user. I tried setting `wait` to `10` and `dont_filter` to `True`, but it isn't working. What should I do now?

Here is my spider:

```
import scrapy
from disqus.items import DisqusItem

class DisqusSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "disqusSpider"
    start_urls = ["https://disqus.com/by/disqus_sAggacVY39/", "https://disqus.com/by/VladimirUlayanov/", "https://disqus.com/by/Beasleyhillman/", "https://disqus.com/by/Slick312/"]
    splash_def = {"endpoint" : "render.html", "args" : {"wait" : 10}}

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = self.parse_basic, dont_filter = True, meta = {
                "splash" : self.splash_def,
                "base_profile_url" : url
            })

    def parse_basic(self, response):
        name = response.css("h1.cover-profile-name.text-largest.truncate-line::text").extract_first()
        disqusItem = DisqusItem(name = name)
        request = scrapy.Request(url = response.meta["base_profile_url"] + "followers/", callback = self.parse_followers, dont_filter = True, meta = {
            "item" : disqusItem,
            "base_profile_url" : response.meta["base_profile_url"],
            "splash": self.splash_def
        })
        print "parse_basic", response.url, request.url
        yield request

    def parse_followers(self, response):
        print "parse_followers", response.meta["base_profile_url"], response.meta["item"]
        followers = response.css("div.user-info a::attr(href)").extract()
```

`DisqusItem` is defined as follows:

```
class DisqusItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    followers = scrapy.Field()
```

Here are the results:

```
2017-08-07 23:09:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
parse_followers https://disqus.com/by/disqus_sAggacVY39/ {'name': u'Trailer Trash'}
2017-08-07 23:09:14 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 5 pages (at 5 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-07 23:09:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
parse_followers https://disqus.com/by/VladimirUlayanov/ {'name': u'Trailer Trash'}
2017-08-07 23:09:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
parse_followers https://disqus.com/by/Beasleyhillman/ {'name': u'Trailer Trash'}
2017-08-07 23:09:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
parse_followers https://disqus.com/by/Slick312/ {'name': u'Trailer Trash'}
```

Here is the file `settings.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Scrapy settings for disqus project
#

BOT_NAME = 'disqus'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['disqus.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'disqus.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050' 

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapyjs.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
DUPEFILTER_DEBUG = True

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 10
```

Comment: Looks like splash is giving scrapy the same initially rendered html regardless of the url. Does adding a wait help: `'args':{'wait': 2}` (2 seconds)?

Comment: I have `"args" : {"wait" : 10}` already. Take a look at the attribute `splash_def`. However, it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Ah, yes, missed that, thanks. Don't have a way to debug at this point, will check back later if nobody will help.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for taking a look at this post.

Comment: Could you try replacing `"splash" : self.splash_def` with `"splash": self.spash_def.copy()` everywhere?

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using SplashRequest instead of scrapy.Request.

ex:

```
import scrapy
from disqus.items import DisqusItem
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class DisqusSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "disqusSpider"
    start_urls = ["https://disqus.com/by/disqus_sAggacVY39/", "https://disqus.com/by/VladimirUlayanov/", "https://disqus.com/by/Beasleyhillman/", "https://disqus.com/by/Slick312/"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_basic, dont_filter = True, endpoint='render.json',
                        args={
                            'wait': 2,
                            'html': 1
                        })
```

Comment: Thank you! I will test your solution tomorrow. It would be even better if you explained the changes and differences in arguments. :)

Comment: I just changed scrapy.Request to SplashRequest, which is the preferred method for splash requests.  endpoint='render.json' means that it returns a json encoded dictionary, and 'html': 1 means it also gets the html.  It would also work if you just set endpoint='render.html'.  Let me know if this works for you, I'm not exactly sure why it makes a difference.

Comment: Your solution works, so I accepted the answer. :) Thanks. :)